# First Data Patament Gateway- No option to download 'digital certificate' (.PEM) file in Download Center

Tags: php, api, payment-gateway, gateway, firstdata

I am trying to integrate First Data payment gateway in my PHP project, i have created a First Data Global Gateway Web Service API TEST ACCOUNT, It's configuaration needs a digital certificate (.pem), In all documentation, it is clearly mention the steps to download this file.

```
To download your digital certificate, please use the Global Gateway Virtual Terminal.

Access the Global Gateway download center in the Virtual Terminal Support section:

- Visit https://www.staging.yourpay.com

- Log in to the Virtual Terminal

- Click on "Support" in the Main Menu Bar.

- Click on the word "Download Center" under Downloads in the Side Menu Box.

- Click on "Download Now" Store PEM File section on main page.
```

But in my test account i am not able to see any download option for .PEM file (Store PEM Files), i can see only one download link in this page i.e 'Store CERT Files' and this file also not downloading. Please any one help to download Store PEM File.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I am facing the same issue....

Comment: YOU CAN GET COMPLETE EXAMPLE HERE http://ashokks.com/First-Data-Global-Gateway-Web-Service-API-Complete-PHP-Example

Answer (score 2):

You can Download the Certificates using **Internet Explorer** Browser. The Firefox, Chrome and other browsers not support to download.

Important thing is

> - Use "111111111" as your Tax ID for your test account.  For production stores you will be required to supply your actual SSN or
>     Tax ID submitted in the merchant account boarding process.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to download it using Safari 5.1.10 on Mac OSX 10.6.8.

Comment: The question asked how to download a file. The other answer mentions that the download works in IE, but not in Chrome or Firefox. This answer mentions that the download works in Safari. The question itself is of questionable quality, but it seems to me that using the low quality question as context, the answers are acceptable.